# Looking for a Weasel-word spell checker

Tags: text-editor, language, spell-checker, grammar

Recommends using precise terminology when "weasel words" are detected.

Similar concept to the Simple Terminology checker mentioned on this site that detects jargon words. Perhaps similar to some language training agent programs that replace inline terms with the target language.

This could be a capability already existing in a spell-checker tool if it allows one to import a blacklist, such as a list of profanities. Probably difficult to cover a lot of cases involving phrases, but worth a shot.

In any case, if I type "ASAP" or "As Soon As Possible" it should provide an inline list of recommendations "By close of day today", "by {next hour}, etc.

Not looking for a script to process text after it is written - this should be an OS level service that I can give permission to look over my shoulder in any context where I am typing text.

Prefer FOSS with MAC OS

Comment: Not a service that is available / plugin that is active when you are typing something, but perhaps look at the [OpenAI Software-As-a-Service offerings for Text Transformation](https://beta.openai.com/examples?category=transformation):   They have a tunable Too-Long Didnt read summarizer for instance.

Comment: Welcome David!  Please edit your answer (and tags) to include the target operating system(s) and any price constraints.  Thanks, and again, welcome!